# Do these series converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need some help to tell whether or not these series converge:

For $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \sin (\sqrt {n+1}-\sqrt n)$$ using the telescoping series criteria I proved that $\sum_{i=0}^\infty (\sqrt {n+1}-\sqrt n)$ does not converge but I don't know what to do next.

And for $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \log (n  \sin(1/n))$$ here I don't know what to do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the $\log$ one, you might want to use the fact that $$ \displaystyle\sum_{i} \log(x_i) = \log \left( \displaystyle\prod_{i} x_i \right). $$This may or may not help, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\sin(x) > \dfrac{2x}{\pi}$ for $x \in (0,\pi/2)$. Hence,
$$\sum_{n=0}^N \sin(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}) > \dfrac2{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^N (\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}) = \dfrac{2\sqrt{N+1}}{\pi}$$

Answer (score 1):

(Here all approximations are comparing the highest-order term as $n \to \infty$)

$\sin(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}) = \sin \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} \approx \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$ and then use the limit comparison test.

$\log( n \sin \frac{1}{n} ) = \log( 1 + n ( \sin \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n} ) ) \approx n ( \sin \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n} ) \approx n ( -\frac{1}{6n^3} ) = -\frac{1}{6n^2}$ and then use the limit comparison test. (note that the first approximation is valid because $n ( \sin \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n} ) \to 0$)

Answer (score 0):

For the second problem: we can rewrite the sum as
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log (n  \sin(1/n)) = 
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log (n)  + 
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log(\sin(1/n))
$$

Noting that $\sin(1/n)<1/n$, we have
$$
\log (n)  + 
\log(\sin(1/n)) <
 \log (n)  + 
 \log(1/n) =
 \log (n\cdot (1/n))=0
$$
So that each term in the sequence is negative, which means that the partial sums form a monotonically decreasing sequence. On the other hand, we note that $\sin(1/n) > \frac 1n - \frac 1{6n^3}$ (the third order Taylor approximation), so that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log (n)  + 
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log(\sin(1/n)) >
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log (n)  + 
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log \left(\frac 1n - \frac 1{6n^3}\right) =\\
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log \left(n \left(\frac 1n - \frac 1{6n^3}\right)\right)=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log \left(1 - \frac 1{6n^2}\right)
$$
I am fairly certain that the above series converges and can be shown to do so via the integral test, [using integration by parts](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20from%201%20to%20infinity%20%5Clog%20%281%20-%201/%286n%5E2%29%29%20dn).

Because the above holds, the sum is bounded below and therefore must converge.